# Cover letter clarification for a lecturer position

Tags: faculty-application, application-cover-letter, lecturer

I want to apply for a lecturer job and in the section of the cover letter it says this:

> Please attach your covering letter describing how you meet the
> criteria on the Person Specification. You should use the competency
> headings of the Person Specification in your covering letter,
> providing examples of how you fulfil each one. You should also take
> into consideration the Job Description provided.

Does it mean I have to **refer** to the Person specification titles while writing the cover letter (which seems more logical) or actually **paste** the PS titles inside the cover letter?

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing it, I'd assume that they want you to use those headings as an outline. They probably want to lay several applications side by side and compare them easily. Just guessing, though.

Comment: What would be the difference? To refer to the titles, you need to copy them to your cover letter (technically, copy+paste is one way to implement this).

Comment: @lighthouse keeper, Thanks! I refer to the titles of course but I'm wondering if they want to use them as headings before each paragraph so it makes their life easier.

Comment: Thanks @Buffy that is my understanding as well.

Comment: OK, that didn't get clear from your question (you may want to modify it).

Comment: Your confusion confuses me. I don't get what the difference is?

Comment: user2705196 I meant whether they had to be used as headings on top of each paragraphs so they would clearly signify what each paragraph was talking about or if they just wanted us to make a reference integrated in the narrative. But to be honest, I don't think I should stress so much about it. Hopefully they'll read the whole letter.

Comment: Please identify the country you are asking about.  I'll guess UK?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should paste the headings into your coverletter and format them as headings.  If they are numbered, keep the numbering.

Probably the hiring committee will need to rate your responses to each heading.  Format your letter to make it easy for them.

Comment: Many thanks all! I used them as headings eventually so fingers crossed :)